# Why isnt the menubar showing on mobile devices? (html)

Tags: html, mobile, resize, menubar, titlebar

my site is working normally on desktop ( www.spraint.nl ) and when I resize it, the menubar properly adjusts to the size. But when I visit it from a mobile device, the menubar just disappears. Can someone point it out through my code?

HTML

```
                    <!-- Header -->
                        <header id="header">                                
                            <div class="inner">
                                <!-- Logo -->
                                    <h1> <a href="index.html" id="logo" style="width:250px;height:78px;margin-top:-25px;margin-left:-36px;"> Klusbedrijf Spraint </a> </h1>


                                <!-- Nav -->
                                    <nav id="nav">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="current_page_item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>


                                            <li><a href="spuittechniek.html">Spuittechniek</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="galerij.html">Galerij</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="referenties.html">Referenties</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </nav>

                            </div>
                        </header>
```

Javascript:

```
        // Title Bar.
            $(
                '<div id="titleBar">' +
                    '<a href="#navPanel" class="toggle"></a>' +
                    '<span class="title">' + $('#logo').html() + '</span>' +
                '</div>'
            )
                .appendTo($body);
```

Comment: You should include the relevant CSS. Also specify if you are using any CSS frameworks (Bootstrap, Materialize, etc.).

Comment: I have used a HTML5 template, so my css file is about 2000 lines long :p (template ZeroFour from html5up.net)